# What development environment setup steps am I missing?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm working on a database project for my school's science fair. I need to insert some data from a .aspx webform into an access database. I've been using "Microsoft Visual Web Developer" to write the following .aspx.vb code. However when I press the "submit" button it doesn't send the data to the database as it should. 
What development environment setup steps am I missing?

I've been following this tutorial (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=szm3BFSOVw0).
Here's the aspx source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
</script>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head id="Head1" runat="server"></head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Science Fair Registration</title>

<form id="form1" runat="server" class="auto-style1">
    <br />
     <%-- Graphics--%>
     <center><h1>Science Fair Registration</h1></center>
    <asp:MultiView id="MultiView1" runat="server" ActiveViewIndex="0">
        <asp:View id="View1" runat="server">

            <br />
            First Name:<br />
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBoxSFirst" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Last Name:<br />
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBoxSLast" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Student Email Address:<br />
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBoxSEmail" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            School:<br />
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBoxSchool" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Grade:<br />
            <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownListGrade" runat="server" Width="86px">
                <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            Teacher's Last Name (only):<br />
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBoxTLastName" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Teacher E-mail:<br />&nbsp;<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxTEmail" runat="server" 
                Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br /> 
            <%-- Teacher Phone Number:<br />&nbsp;<asp:TextBox id="TPhone" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox> --%>
            <%-- Might put the above in later --%>
            <br />
            <br />Catagory :<br />&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList id="DropDownListCatagory" runat="server" Width="212px">
                <asp:ListItem>Behavorial &amp; Social Sciences</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Biochemistry &amp; Microbiology</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Botany</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Environmental Sciences</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Medicine &amp; Health</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Zoology</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Chemistry</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Computer Science</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Earth &amp; Space Sciences</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Engineering</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Mathematics</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem>Physics</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            Exibit Title :<br />&nbsp;<asp:TextBox id="TextBoxTitle" runat="server" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Does your exhibit use electricity?<br />
            <%-- Possible issues here, may need to use 1 & 0 instead--%>
            <asp:DropDownList id="DropDownListElectricity" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="True">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="False">No</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click" 
                style="height: 26px" />
            <br />

        </asp:View>
    </asp:MultiView>
</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is the aspx.vb source:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class _Default1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'form data requests---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim strName As String = Request.Form("First") 'In paraenthesis may be the item name in the form
        Dim strLast As String = Request.Form("Last")
        Dim strStudentEmail As String = Request.Form("StudentEmail")

        Dim strSchool As String = Request.Form("School")
        Dim numGrade As Integer = Request.Form("Grade") '*Dropdown list
        Dim strTeacher As String = Request.Form("Teacher") 'Teacher's last name
        Dim strTeacherEmail As String = Request.Form("TeacherEmail")

        Dim strCatagory As String = Request.Form("Catagory") '*Dropdown list
        Dim strTitle As String = Request.Form("Title")
        Dim boolElectricity As Boolean = Request.Form("Electricity") '*possible boolean for electricity


        'Open Db Connection---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Dim strSQL As String
        Dim dbconn As OleDbConnection = Nothing

        dbconn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("sf13.mdb"))
        dbconn.Open();


        'SQL actions ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        strSQL = "insert into Exhibits (First, Last, School, Teacher, Title, Grade, Category, TeacherNumber, StudentEmail, Electricity, TeacherEmail) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
        objcmd = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, dbconn) 'OleDbCommand should be highlighted - missing an imports....

        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@First", strName))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Last", strLast))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@School", strSchool))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Teacher", strTeacher))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Title", strTitle))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Grade", numGrade))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Category", strCatagory))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@StudentEmail", strStudentEmail))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Electricity", boolElectricity))
        objcmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@TeacherEmail", strTeacherEmail))
        objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'Close DB Connection
        dbconn.Close()
        Response.Write("Thank you for registering")

    End Sub

End Class
```

Fixed it
I changed the language to VB and added a "code behind tag".

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ScienceFair.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors? VS has a brilliant debugger, do you know how to use it? If not, please do read some tutorials. If you do or once you do feel comfortable with it, put some breakpoints in and track exactly how far your code is getting.

Comment: You defined `Button1_Click()` twice.  Get rid of the empty one that is declared at the top of your markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing in-line coding style with code-behind. Try changing the page language to VB and specifying the code-behind class:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Inherits="_Default1" %>
```

Also, remove the script block at the start of the file.

**Further Reading**

- [ASP.NET Code-Behind Model Overview](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303247)

Comment: That is what I want to do, but those changes gave me errors.
Err1----------:
Parser Error Message: Could not load type '_Default1'.
Source Error: 
Line 2:  <%@ Page Language="VB" Inherits="_Default1" %>
Err2----------:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.default1_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Button1_Click' and no extension method 'Button1_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.default1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Source Error:
Line 78:    <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="Button1_Click"

Comment: @NickGilpin What's the [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt9tafza.aspx) of your `_Default1` class? If there's not defined one in the VB file, check the project properties.